# How does django's ORM get one to one fields without having to call a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

So let's say I have a django model like so:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

After creating this one to one field, the profile object can be accessed by doing `user_instance.profile`

I've enabled logging for the ORM to see the queries sent to the database using this in my `settings.py` file:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

I then opened the shell using `python3 manage.py shell` and executed the following:

```
firstuser = User.objects.first()
```

This resulted in the following query logged out:

```
SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."password", "users_user"."last_login", "users_user"."is_superuser", "users_user"."username", "users_user"."is_staff", "users_user"."is_active", "users_user"."date_joined", "users_user"."name", "users_user"."email", "users_user"."join_date", "users_user"."date_of_birth" FROM "users_user" ORDER BY "users_user"."id" ASC LIMIT 1; args=()
```

Further I did:

```py
firstuser.profile
```

And got this query logged out:

```
SELECT "users_profile"."id", "users_profile"."user_id", "users_profile"."status", "users_profile"."institute" FROM "users_profile" WHERE "users_profile"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 21; args=(1,)
```

So, how does django execute a query when I request a related object **without having to call any functions within my own code**.

Is there a python method to override behaviour of how attributes from a class are read?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to know how django does these lazy evaluations without calling any functions within my code

Comment: What do you mean by "how django does these lazy evaluations" with "without calling any functions within my code"? What is your question? Do you want to know how django does those stuff? what do you mean by not calling any functions?

Comment: The underlying mechanism in python is called the [Descriptor Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: @NavidZarepak In my code as mentioned above I read the attribute `user.profile`, and I get the profile object lazily loaded when I access it. In my code I donot call anything like `get_profile`

Comment: @Wombatz Exactly what I was trying to know about, thanks a lot Wombatz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python `Descriptors` let objects customize attribute lookup, storage, and deletion.

The underlying mechanism is called [Descriptor Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) (Thanks to Wombatz for pointing this out)

The `property` class allows dynamic computation of an attribute

Example:

```py
import random

class MyClass:
    @property
    def random(self):
        return random.random()

my_object = MyClass()

for _ in range(3):
    print(my_object.random)
```

Output:

```py
0.23871118861024354
0.877585489346098
0.9753110448271668
```